# Oracle Temporary Tables has "data block corrupted"?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, temporary, oraoledb

Within a packaged SP I am populating a Temporary Table. At the end of the procedure processing I read the Temporary Table into a ref cursor.

When I try to execute the procedure in SQL Developer everything works as it should.

When I try to execute the procedure in a Classic ASP page (using OraOLEDB) the IIS logs show "ORA-01578:_ORACLE_data_block_corrupted".

When I first saw this, and before I tried it in SQL Developer, I thought the tablespace file was corrupted so I dropped the tablespace; recreated it on another disk and then told the user that the new tablespace was the new temporary area.

Tried again, same thing only referring to the new tablespace !

I presume that there's something about my use of Temporary Tables which is causing this problem ?

In case it's significant what I'm trying to do here is to reuse an old, complex SP which used to return a number of Table (associative array) objects. I don't want to change too much about the SP so I've got it writing the data that was previously placed into the associative arrays into the temporary table. Then I dump the contents of the TT into the ref-cursor. I can't see how any of that would create the "data block corrupted" message but I hope someone can tell me.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that your db is facing some curruption issue with your temp file. i would suggest you to create another temp file in your temp tablespace and drop the old temp file after that. Then you will see if your issue is solved or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I mentioned in my question I have already gone through the process of creating a new temp space and dropping the old one. Unfortunately the error is seen again with the new tablespace.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/364088/glaucon  Did you get any solution for the issue. I am facing the same issue with my environment.

Comment: @NeerajSharma - I'm sorry I really can't remember how I resolved this or even if I did, It's possible that I may have done some different implementation.